# Write Nginx Config as Unprivileged User

Tags: sudo

I have a deployment script that gets executed by an unprivileged `deploy` user. To fully automate things, though, I have to write a web server configuration file to `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and symlink it in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

I'd rather not change ownership or permissions for this particular directory so I've been trying to figure out a way to do this with password-less sudo access. Since I'm here, I guess it's pretty clear that I haven't had any luck.

Is there any way to update my `sudoers` file such that the `deploy` user can write new files to those directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try writing a `NOPASSWD` rule like so:

```
deploy ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp -t /etc/nginx/sites-available *, /bin/ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Then the `deploy` use would directly copy to the `sites-available` folder, after creating the configuration elsewhere, then create the link (without a target name being specified).

This might have loopholes too.

Or you could write a script that manages all this, and have a single `NOPASSWD` rule with only that script.

Comment: This is similar to what I've been trying, but I'll play with it. You have some syntax in here that I definitely haven't tried. This is a staging server, so I'm not _overly_ concerned about security--I just want to avoid doing anything ridiculously open. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobWilkerson A single site configuration file can have multiple `server` definitions, so the simplest way maybe to create (and link) a file (say `/etc/nginx/sites-available/deploy.conf`), and give `deploy` write access to that file only (using `chown` + `chmod`).

Comment: yeah, but that's against our convention (1 conf file per project/site) and it means automated appends to a file that could get huge. I'd really like to keep this within our existing standards even though it's hard. Hopefully it's not actually impossible.

Comment: 2 things with your syntax: 1. I'm getting prompted for a password, and 2. even after entering it, permission is still denied. As `deploy`, have created a file in my home and tried to `mv`/`cp` it to `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. Did I miss something?

Comment: What was the exact command you used?

Comment: That's all I needed. The `mv` command wasn't quite precise enough to match the `sudoers` entry. I think I have it sorted out. Thanks very much for your help. This was huge.